# Ignore first and last records using LogicApp

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a very simple LogicApp where I want to ignore the first and last x number of records, the definition is below which you should be able to see my result:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Convert_Each_Row_into_Array": {
                "inputs": "@split(variables('CSV Data'),'\n')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_CSV_Data": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Initialize_CSV_Data": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "CSV Data",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "rubbish1,rubbish2,rubbish3\nblank1,blank2,blank3\nheader1,header2,header3\ndata1,data2,data3\ndata4,data5,data6\ndata7,data8,data9"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@triggerBody()",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "NumberOfFooterRows": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "NumberOfHeaderRows": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Skip_Footer": {
                "inputs": "@take(outputs('Skip_Header'),sub(length(outputs('Skip_Header')),body('Parse_JSON')?['NumberOfFooterRows']))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Skip_Header": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Skip_Header": {
                "inputs": "@take(skip(outputs('Convert_Each_Row_into_Array'),body('Parse_JSON')?['NumberOfHeaderRows']),sub(length(outputs('Convert_Each_Row_into_Array')),1))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Convert_Each_Row_into_Array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

The payload is

```
{
    "NumberOfHeaderRows":3,
    "NumberOfFooterRows":2
}
```

This works fine, but it's for testing only as the real data is in a CSV format stored in a SFTP, so an extra step to get file content is added and then put into Initialise CSV Data variable:
[image]

The CSV file is exactly the same as the original Initialise CSV Data variable, literally just:

```
rubbish1,rubbish2,rubbish3
blank1,blank2,blank3
header1,header2,header3
data1,data2,data3
data4,data5,data6
```

What I'm left with now is this result where it has successfully removed the first 3 rows but not the last 2 rows.  It doesn't give any errors but if I click on the

```
Download (Alt/Option + click)
```

then it just shows

```
[]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `Initialize CSV data` is of string type the skip() skips only the characters that we have mentioned thats why we need to convert the string into array and skip the array objects. Also, seeing the payload to feed we have observed that you are sending string type. Instead, you can send int by making

```
{
    "NumberOfHeaderRows":"3",
    "NumberOfFooterRows":"2"
}
```

to

```
{
    "NumberOfHeaderRows":3,
    "NumberOfFooterRows":2
}
```

### If Array is used

After converting the string type of your csv data to array, it was working. I have included an extra step of `Parse_JSON` just to retrieve the `NumberOfHeaderRows` and `NumberOfFooterRows`which makes things more clear. Here is the screenshots of my logic app -

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

The expression used in `Skip Headers`

```
@take(skip(variables('CSV Data'),body('Parse_JSON')?['NumberOfHeaderRows']),sub(length(variables('CSV Data')),1))
```

The expression used in `Skip Footer`

```
@take(outputs('Skip_Header'),sub(length(outputs('Skip_Header')),body('Parse_JSON')?['NumberOfFooterRows']))
```

Below is my code view:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Initialize_CSV_Data": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "CSV Data",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                "rubbish1,rubbish2,rubbish3",
                                "blank1,blank2,blank3",
                                "header1,header2,header3",
                                "data1,data2,data3",
                                "data4,data5,data6",
                                "data7,data8,data9"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@triggerBody()",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "NumberOfFooterRows": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "NumberOfHeaderRows": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Skip_Footer": {
                "inputs": "@take(outputs('Skip_Header'),sub(length(outputs('Skip_Header')),body('Parse_JSON')?['NumberOfFooterRows']))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Skip_Header": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Skip_Header": {
                "inputs": "@take(skip(variables('CSV Data'),body('Parse_JSON')?['NumberOfHeaderRows']),sub(length(variables('CSV Data')),1))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_CSV_Data": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

### If String is used

Consider you are left with string only, then you can convert that string into array using split function which converts each row into Array object. Here is the logic app

[image]

**RESULT :**

[image]

Here is the expression in `Convert Each Row into Array`

```
split(variables('CSV Data'),'

')
```

Now you can use `Convert Each Row into Array` Connector output to achieve our requirement

Below is the codeview after making the mentioned changes

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Convert_Each_Row_into_Array": {
                "inputs": "@split(variables('CSV Data'),'\n')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_CSV_Data": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Initialize_CSV_Data": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "CSV Data",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "rubbish1,rubbish2,rubbish3\nblank1,blank2,blank3\nheader1,header2,header3\ndata1,data2,data3\ndata4,data5,data6\ndata7,data8,data9"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@triggerBody()",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "NumberOfFooterRows": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "NumberOfHeaderRows": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Skip_Footer": {
                "inputs": "@take(outputs('Skip_Header'),sub(length(outputs('Skip_Header')),body('Parse_JSON')?['NumberOfFooterRows']))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Skip_Header": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Skip_Header": {
                "inputs": "@take(skip(outputs('Convert_Each_Row_into_Array'),body('Parse_JSON')?['NumberOfHeaderRows']),sub(length(outputs('Convert_Each_Row_into_Array')),1))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Convert_Each_Row_into_Array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks again @SwethaKandikonda-MT, think we're almost there, the solution you provided is perfect but I assumed it'd work the same way for if the data is in a CSV stored on a SFTP.  I have updated the question again for more clarity, your help will be much appreciated as I'm seriously running low on brain power!

Comment: @tommyhmt This is because you have only left with 2 rows and those 2 rows are considered as footers and so they are skipping those parts. try giving `NumberOfFooterRows` to be 1 while sending the request or add few more rows to your csv

Comment: Man sorry for being a thick, been a long couple of days, thank you so much for existing the solution is now perfect!